# Why did not the temporary 'Test' did not moved, but only constructed?

Tags: c++, class, rvalue-reference

I was reading the book Scott Meyers's  Effective Modern C++, in which auther mentioned

> "Copies of `rvalues` are generally *move constructed*, while copies of
>   `lvalues` are usually *copy constructed*."

So I wanted to test it by writing a `Test` class which will be temporarily constructed on the go to a `dummy` function which takes rvalue reference as a parameter of `Test` class.

I was expecting to see an output as per the above quote like:

```
Constructed...
Moving...
Hello world
```

But I have only got:

```
Constructed...
Hello world
```

**Why the move constructor didn't call? Is there any undefined behaviour in passing temporary to `dummy` like `dummy(Test{});` ? I am using C++17.**

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test()                       { std::cout << "Constructed...\n"; }
    Test(const Test&)            { std::cout << "Coping...\n"; }
    Test& operator=(const Test&) { std::cout << "Copy=...\n"; return *this; }
    Test(Test&&)                 { std::cout << "Moving...\n"; }
    Test& operator=(Test&&)      { std::cout << "Move=...\n"; return *this; }
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "Hello world\n";
    }
};

void dummy(Test&& test)
{
    test.print();  // is the behavior is good?
}

int main()
{
    dummy(Test{});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pass test by value to observe move-construction.

Comment: @IgorR. *"Pass test by value to observe move-construction."*  isn't it make the `Test` object an lvalue and then shouldn't be a copy constructor call? or did I understand wrong?

Comment: Why would there be a move? `dummy` takes its argument by reference, not by value.

Comment: References to objects are created without calling constructors. `Test &&` by itself is not an instance of class `Test`; it merely refers to some existing instance, so there is no need to call a `Test` constructor to create it.

Comment: *"isn't it make the Test object an lvalue and then shouldn't be a copy constructor call?"* The choice between copy & move constructors depends on the value category of the original object, not the new object. The original object (`Test{}`) is an rvalue in any case. Also note that `Test &&test` itself, despite being called an 'rvalue reference', is an lvalue. You can see that by doing `Test foo(test);` (which will call the copy constructor).

Comment: I'm afraid you did. The key point is that the *argument* the the caller passes is an rvalue.

Comment: Related: [Copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reason copy constructor wouldn't be called for the below code:

```cpp
class Test {
   ...
};

void dummy(Test& t) { // passed as an lvalue reference
   test.print();
}

int main() {
   Test t;
   dummy(t);
   return 0;
}
```

...because the object is passed by reference. In above code, it is an lvalue reference, while it is an rvalue reference in the example you gave, but still a reference.

If you want to pass it by value in contrast, you need to reflect it in your function argument type:

```cpp
void dummy(Test t) {
  ...
}
```

Then the constructor needs to be called for passing `t` by value **unless copy elision takes place, see the addition below**.

Note that `std::move` doesn't actually move anything. It casts the input to rvalue reference and returns it.

---

There is a little nuance though. C++17 guarantees that there won't be a temporary created for prvalue assignments, i.e. `dummy(Test{})` won't invoke copy or move constructor in this case since creating a temporary is elided. Copy elision may still happen in pre-C++17, despite not required by the language. Therefore, make sure to set `-fno-elide-constructors` compiler flag if you'd like to observe move constructor being called in passing prvalue `Test{}` by value to `dummy` function (as in above example).

Answer (score -1):

Basically, only one instance of Test is constructed : `dummy(Test{})` but the move implies that at least two instances exists if you want to move from one to the other.